# Post to Restful api?

Tags: f#

I'm writing the following code to post to a Web API. However, I got compiler error on the line of `client.PostAsJsonAsync`. The error message is

```
Error       This expression was expected to have type
    Async<'a>    
but here has type
    Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage>
```

code:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Model = { ..... }

let PostIt params = async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let content = { ..... } // a Model built from params
    let! response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://...", content) // Error!
    return response }
```

What's the best way to handle Restful API in F#? I'm using Fsharp.Data.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you need to use `Async.AwaitTask`:

```
let! response = Async.AwaitTask (client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://...", content))
```

Or using the `|>` operator:

```
let! response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://...", content) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an F# Data reference, you can also do this using the [F# Data HTTP utilities](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html), which provides an F#-friendly API for making HTTP requests.

```
async {
  let! response = 
    Http.AsyncRequest
      ( "http://httpbin.org/post", httpMethod = "POST",
        headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json ],
        body = TextRequest """ {"test": 42} """)
  return response }
```

F# Data will not automatically serialize data for you though, so the drawback of using these utilities is that you'll need to serialize the data explicitly before making the request.